# Integrated (wp) blog not expanding it's 100% height container

Tags: wordpress, html, height, integration

**Intro:**
I have a page designed simply with html and css, mostly just div's with css to mold the div boxes.

I want to integrate only the blog posts of a wordpress blog site into this page.  Everything in the design is to be the same except for one (large) div that contains the "imported" posts.  I do not want this div to contain it's own scrollbar, as if it's a window to the wp site.  I want the whole site to expand vertically, determined by the height of the wp blog posts, whatever they may be.

I have used the method provided here: http://moshublog.com/2005/07/05/integrate/2/ 
to incorporate the blog, this has worked.

**Problem:**
The div containing this the blog posts ("the loop") does not expand vertically.  It simply cuts the blog post(s) off as if they are not detected.  The height is set to 100% on the div containing it and any div's parent to that one.

**Question:**
How can the div containing the wp blog posts expand vertically based on the height of those blog posts?

**What I've tried:**
- - - Overflow:hidden;  I have floating elements on the page.  I have tried every possibility with overflow:hidden;, which was suggested in any other questions I could find.  This did not change anything.
- - - Making body and html height=100%.  This did not change anything.
- - - Changing the height of the div containing it and any of the parent div's to a fixed height.  This changed the height. If it was larger, then more of the blog posts were seen.  The posts are there, just cut off.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- Main Body Start -->
<div class="clean" style="width:1200px; height:100%; border:0px; margin:0 auto;">

<!-- Body Column One Start -->
<div class="clean" style="width:950px; height:100%; float:left;">
    <!-- Blog Integration Start -->
    <div class="clean" style="width:946px; height:100%; max-width:946px; border-style:none solid; border-color:#99AAFF; 
    border-width:0px 2px; float:left; overflow:hidden; background-color:#ffff77;">

        <div class="clean" style="width:926px; height:100%; margin:0px 10px;">
    <!-- WP Blog code goes in here -->
            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">     
            <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php    
            the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
            </h2>   
            <small>Posted in <?php the_category(', ') ?> on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>  by <?php the_author() ?> &ndash; 
            <?php comments_popup_link('Be the first to comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?> 
            <?php edit_post_link('Edit', ' | ', ''); ?> </small>
            <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content('<span class="more">read more &raquo;</span>') ?>
            </div>
            <?php if(is_single()) {?><p class="postmetadata"><?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?></p><?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft">
            <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="alignright">
            <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>                 
            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/searchform.php"); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Everything below "wp blog code goes here" to "?php endif; ?" is from the wp blog site, and is "the loop".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the height of the divs, doing so will limit them to the height you set them, having said that, if you set the height to 100%, the div will fill 100% of the area of its container, not 100% of its contents, so for the outermost div this will be 100% of the window.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly the answer was looking for.  New problems have arisen, so on to those.  Thanks again, sorry I can't vote you up, I don't have enough req points.